# Redirecting nginx to index.php

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have nginx on a Raspberry Pi.  In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, I replaced `server{}` with the following, and I can access `/var/www/html/index.php` using http://192.168.1.210/.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name $domain_name;
        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html index.htm;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location ~\.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
                try_files $uri =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                # if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break; }
        }
}
```

I now wish to add some simple redirecting similar to Apache's

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I added `if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;` at the end (see the above commented out line) and placed http://192.168.1.210/page2 in the browser, however, the script still doesn't redirect to `/var/www/html/index.php`

How can I redirect any non-existing requests to index.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is to redirect files and directories that do not exist towards index.php?

This can be done by using:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

Or which makes more sense:

```
error_page 404 /index.php;
```

This will also redirect missing files, images, ...

Comment: I had previously tried your first solution, however, it gives the following error: `michael@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
[....] Restarting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.  `systemctl status nginx.service` shows an error, but `journalctl -xn` doesn't show anything.
 failed!`.  Your second solution does not cause an error, but it still doesn't redirect.  Thanks

Comment: You did place that try_files outside location right?

Comment: No, but since did.  Perfect!